# Removing the Google Maps V3 Marker drag animation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I drag and drop a marker it raises a little bit and a skewed X appears underneath it to denote dragging position.

Is there anyway to get rid of this completely? I have custom markers and would like to display their dragging state in a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`raiseOnDrag` is undocumented in the current API version (3.17). Instead there is a `crossOnDrag` property:

`crossOnDrag` : *boolean    - If false, disables cross that appears beneath the marker when dragging. This option is true by default.*

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

---

*Edit (Sep. 2016): `raiseOnDrag` is still undocumented in 3.25*

Answer (score 8):

You can set the property of the marker raiseOnDrag to false

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  draggable: true,
  map: map,
  raiseOnDrag: false
});
```

And then you could use ScottE solution to create a custom drag effect.

Comment: `raiseOnDrag` is still an undocumented property. Use at your own risks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible. You can change the marker on dragstart / dragend, but this doesn't change the 'x' that shows up underneath.

Here is an example of changing the marker when dragging:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-imagechange.html

When you look at the images you'll see that the 'x' is not part of the png.

Comment: I haven't found anything either, if I'm still at a loss through-out the next week I'll accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: This is still the accepted answer, 5 years later, although it does not answer OP question.

Comment: down voting because there is an api as other answer shows

Answer (score -1):

You also need to then switch the original image back on dragend event.

complete code is like this:

```
myArrow         = new google.maps.MarkerImage("defaultIcon.png"); 
myArrowDrag     = new google.maps.MarkerImage("draggingIcon.png"); 

myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng),
    map         : map,
    icon        : myArrow,
    draggable   : true,
    raiseOnDrag : false
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function() {
    myMarker.setOptions({icon: myArrowDrag});
});
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function() {
    myMarker.setOptions({icon: myArrow});
});
```

Comment: This makes use of undocumented properties + does not answer OP question.