# iOS Google Maps marker dragging animation

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

When you drag a marker, the `GMSMapView` slightly slides down.
How to disable this animation?
Looks like in *javascript* it can be disabled:
[Removing the Google Maps V3 Marker drag animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681754/removing-the-google-maps-v3-marker-drag-animation)

Answer (score -1):

You can define if the marker can be dragged when you create the marker in your js file. For example:

```
myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position    : new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng),
map         : map,
draggable   : false
});
```

Same thing for the animation:

```
myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position    : new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng),
map         : map,
draggable   : false,
animation   : none
});
```